# React Native & Firebase Cloud Messaging: How to avoid duplicated push notification?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have one website(`React`) and mobile app (`React Native`) which are both connected with the same `Firebase` Projects.
I have a button inside my Website; every time I click the button, my application receives a push notification from firebase (`Firebase Cloud Messaging`).
However, in case of slow internet connection or browser gets refreshed, my user is able to send a duplicated push notification.

How do I avoid this duplicated push notifications situation? In other word, I want to replace the old push notification every time I get a new push notification.

Comment: What library you are using for receiving push notification in react native application?

Comment: I am using `@react-native-firebase/messaging`. Looks like a lot of people hates my question lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear all notification before showing new notification. Version 6 do not handle provide functionality to remove notification. But you can use version 5. It has [cancelAllNotifications](https://v5.rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/reference/Notifications#cancelAllNotifications) method. You can also use [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification).

Comment: When you said about Version 6 and version 5, are you talking about React-Native or the push notification plugin?

Comment: react-native-firebase